# Search cities and hotels in cities and retrieving hotels name using Bing Maps in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, bing-maps, windows-store

I am using Bing Maps in my Store application for Windows 8.1 . I have combo box which includes cities name . I want to get all hotels particular to that cities in my Map control.How to do that I learn to add pushpins , traffic etc but unable to do so . Can anyone provide me code samples or tutorials.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the NAVTEQ POI data sources in the Bing Spatial Data Services.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478189.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585126.aspx

I wrote a free ebook on creating Location Intelligent Windows Store apps. Chapter 6 has a walk through of how to do exactly what you are looking for. You can download a free copy of the book here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/my-book/

You can also find all the code samples for the book here:  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Location-Intelligence-for-1c691d0e